# In Swift, I got EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x1fedad19a120) while executing Peterson's Algorithms

Tags: swift, algorithm

### circumstance

I executed below code for checking Peterson's Algorithms in sample app not playgrounds.

If code will correctly be executed, I will get `sum` as 0

But instead, I got error message

#### ⬇️ error message

[image]

#### Question

I can't understand why this message popped up.

Could you help me teach some reason about why this happen?

#### ⬇️ Code

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var group = DispatchGroup()
    var sum = 0
    var flag = [false, false,false , false ]
    var turn = 0


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad() 
        var queue = DispatchQueue(label: "producer")
        var queue2 = DispatchQueue(label: "consumer")

        queue.async(group: group) {
            self.producer()
        }
        queue2.async(group: group) {
            self.consumer()

        }

        group.notify(queue: .main) {
            print(self.sum)
        }
    }

    func producer() {
        for i in 0..<10000 {
            flag[0] = true
            turn = 1
            while flag[1] && turn == 1 { }

            sum += 1
            flag[0] = false
        }
    }


    func consumer() {
        for i in 0..<10000 {
            flag[1] = true
            turn = 0
            while flag[0] && turn == 0  { }

            sum -= 1
            flag[1] = false
        }
    }

    
}
```

Comment: You're most likely experiencing a race condition. You're accessing the same array from two different queues, without any synchronization.

Comment: @mag_zbc  thank you for replying for me.   Yes,  I knew that different queues are accessing the same array.  but this will be not causing crash.  Instead of crashing they will get some result like that sum is not 0 or etc.  but I got crash.

Comment: You're forgetting that in Swift Arrays are value types. Writing to an array, even to different index, means mutating the structure itself, hence the race condition. Perhaps because of this Peterson's Algorithm can't be properly implemented in Swift, at least not in this way.

Comment: @mag_zbc    thank you for replying.  but if I remove ```while flag[0] && turn == 0  { }``` in producer, consumer method , there is no crash.

Comment: Race condition can mean two queues are trying to write the same data at the same time, or one tries to write while the other tries to read.

Comment: @mag_zbc    thank you for replying.  oh... I misunderstand race condition in swift.    Until now, I knew that race condition can cause unexpected result, not crash.   but now It can be causing crash!!   I didn't know that..  thank you.   but   I wonder last one,   is race condition always causing crash ?

Comment: set target ```var queue2 = DispatchQueue(label: "consumer", target: .main)``` now it will not crash